# Trying to extract word embeddings but keep getting CUDA out of memory error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, word-embedding

I'm trying to extract the word embeddings of my corpus (5017 samples), but I keep getting "OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 7.50 GiB (GPU 0; 39.56 GiB total capacity; 38.08 GiB already allocated; 110.56 MiB free; 38.14 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF" even when I divided my corpus into 2 parts

```
model_name = "aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv2"
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name, output_hidden_states = True)
model.eval()
model = model.to(device)

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenized_texts = []
for text in corpus:
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize("[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]")
    tokenized_texts.append(tokenized_text)
print(tokenized_texts)

max_seq_length = 512
chunked_tokenized_texts = []
for tokens in tokenized_texts:
    for i in range(0, len(tokens), max_seq_length - 2):
        chunk = tokens[i:i + max_seq_length - 2]
        chunk = ["[CLS]"] + chunk + ["[SEP]"]

indexed_tokens = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(chunk) for chunk in chunked_tokenized_texts]

max_seq_length = max(len(chunk) for chunk in indexed_tokens)
indexed_tokens_padded = [chunk + [0] * (max_seq_length - len(chunk)) for chunk in indexed_tokens]

tokens_tensor = torch.tensor(indexed_tokens_padded)
segments_tensors = torch.ones_like(tokens_tensor)
tokens_tensor = tokens_tensor.to(device)
segments_tensors = segments_tensors.to(device)

# Extract word embeddings for the entire corpus
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)
```

Comment: Try 
Splitting the corpus, lower the sequence length params and use a model with lower dimensional embedding